# (How) am I supposed to destroy a uv_async_t?

Tags: node.js, strict-aliasing, libuv

After I'm done with a `uv_async_t`, I'm supposed to destroy it to avoid any leaks, right?  From glancing at the docs, it appears I'm supposed to use `uv_close()` for this, but it takes a `uv_handle_t*`, not a `uv_async_t*`.  Furthermore, it looks like casting it (as in `uv_close((uv_handle_t *)async, NULL)`) would cause a strict aliasing violation.  Is that what I'm supposed to do anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to cast the `uv_async_t*` to `uv_handle_t*`. That's how libuv internally works.

All handles share the base structure, so IIRC strict aliasing rules are not broken because it amounts to casting it to the first member of the structure.

A note on your example call to `uv_close`: you can only free the memory for a handle in the close callback, not before, so if you pass NULL and the handle was allocated on the heap you won't know when you can free the memory.

Comment: Unfortunately `uv_async_t` doesn't have a `uv_handle_t` as its first member; instead, it [duplicates the fields](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.9.1/include/uv.h#L761).  But yeah looks like that's what I'm supposed to do anyway.  Thanks for the tip about the `uv_close()` callback!