# Ensure asynchonous callback is called by libuv

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, callback, libuv

The [documentation of libuv states](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/async.html?highlight=uv_async_send):

> libuv will coalesce calls to uv_async_send(), that is, not every call
>   to it will yield an execution of the callback. For example: if
>   uv_async_send() is called 5 times in a row before the callback is
>   called, the callback will only be called once. If uv_async_send() is
>   called again after the callback was called, it will be called again.

So in case I need a guarantee that each time I make a call to `uv_async_send()` my callback gets called with the correct payload is it sufficient to have a distinct `uv_async_t` handle? For example, is it save to allocate a new `uv_async_t` on the heap, fill its `data` member, call `uv_async_init` and `uv_async_send` and in the processing callback close the handle using `uv_close` and then delete it? Does it matter which thread constructs the `uv_async_t` and which thread calls `uv_async_init`?

**EDIT**

1. According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/libuv/Ef0-NblPVis) it **does** matter which thread calls `uv_async_init`.
2. According to an [answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38875621/1557062) one has to take care to delete the `uv_async_t` only after the close callback passed to `uv_close` had been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a thread-safe queue and a single async handle. When you need a callback called, create some soft of structure to hold it, put it in the queue and call `uv_async_send`, then in the callback process the queue until it's empty.

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution, but if I understand correctly now `uv_async_init` has to be called prior to the start of the loop, doesn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it does need to be called in the loop thread.